# How to change the issue Type of an issue in JIRA via email?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, jira

I am working on an MVC application that is currently sending an email to JIRA and it is creating an issue. I am currently configuring all of the required fields and currently the issue being created has the issue Type set to bug as a default and also I think the priority set to minor.

I need to be able to change these two fields from the default as this application is used for clients that need to choose the correct issue and priority.

Currently I am using the TO, FROM, CC as the assignees, client and reporter.  The summary and description are used by the subject and body respectively.  This is why I don't know if it is actually possible to change these.

Can this actually be done, for example in the body **"issueType" = "BUG"**, or **"issueType":"Task"**?

The application has the IssueType and Priority as dropdown list so could I append this to the body or maybe the subject of the email and send it.  All code is working just need to know how/if I can set these two properties.

**Update**

I saw an example of this being used but I am unsure of how to implement this into an email form or if this can be done.  And I am also using smtp gmail to send the information in my MVC application.

handler.params:    project=XXOODD, issuetype=2

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/39041/jira-creating-issues-and-comments-from-email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default this cannot be done, but by using a couple of add-ons you can successfully get it to work:

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.metainf.jira.plugin.emailissue

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.javahollic.jira.jemh-ui